# Partially fetching audio

Tags: html, webkit, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to utilise a web API to download the first `n` seconds of an audio file. Browsers are obviously able to fetch sections of audio (done while streaming audio); is this functionality exposed via some form of API?

Answer (score 0):

WebAudio doesn't provide any such capability.  I think your best bet is to look at [WebCodecs](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/).